# Class SoapClient not found

Tags: php, laravel, soap, composer-php, soap-client

I use php 7.2.34 and laravel 6. I encountered mentioned error and after trying some solution my problem didn't solve.

I did some of the things below:

- composer update and self-update.
- composer dump-autoload.
- removing `;` in `;extension=soap` in `php.ini`.
- `sudo apt-get install php7.2-soap` and `sudo systemctl restart nginx.service`. The response for `sudo apt-get install php7.2-soap` was as follows:

```
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php7.2-soap is already the newest version (7.2.34-40+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded."
```

I have soap in result of `phpinfo()` as you see in the picture. but I don't have it in result of composer show.

[image]

Comment: Web and cli can have different PHP packages installed. You may need to double-check the plugin directory for the CLI and see if the soap extension is there

Comment: I checked CLI folder of php7.2 and changed it.

Comment: Are you attempting to access the SOAP extension from the web or the CLI

Comment: What makes you think that this problem is related to Composer or Laravel? Also, keep in mind that PHP 7.2 is horribly outdated